# Zipping an empty iterable

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

I want to loop through an iterable of tuples and store each value in a new variable. I can do this with zip:
`x, y = zip(*enumerate(range(0,30,5)))`

But this doesn't work if the iterable is empty

```py
x, y = zip(*enumerate(range(0,-1,5)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3267, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-35-76960294a673>", line 1, in <module>
    x, y = zip(*enumerate(range(0,-1,5)))
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 0)
```

Because zip returns an empty iterable instead of an iterable containing two empty lists

How can I handle the case where the iterable is empty?

Comment: @ReutSharabani that was the point. He purposefully made an empty iterator as an example

Comment: @user2357112 good point

Comment: is `for x, y in enumerate(range(0,30,5)):` not going to work? Do you specifically need `x` and `y` as tuples to reuse later?

Comment: @Dan I need explicit tuples for use later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Awkward special casing:

```
x, y = [*zip(*your_iterable)] or [(), ()]
```

or just not using `zip(*...)`. Your `zip(*enumerate(...))` can be replaced by constructing the indices with `range`:

```
y = tuple(range(0,-1,5))
x = tuple(range(len(y)))
```

I'm calling `tuple` here to replicate the behavior of `zip`, but depending on what you're doing, that may not be necessary.

Comment: Second example here is probably the best way to go about it. Your future self will thank you :)

Comment: Second example works nicely for kicking out enumerate.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a default you can always extend the unpacking manually to ensure at least two arguments:

```
x, y, *_ = *zip(*enumerate(range(0,-1,5))), [], []
```